# Conda enviroment don't activate in vs code with powershell

Tags: python, powershell, visual-studio-code, conda, miniconda

I want to run conda enviroment for python 3.10 programming in vs code V.1.80.0 with power shell temrinal V.5.1.19041.2364 and W10. I install miniconda3  (conda 23.5.0) and can list, create and revome  enviroments but when i try to activate a enviroment in vs code dont activate and dont giveme a error message.

powershell output:

```
PS C:\Users\Julián\Documents\proyectos\conda> conda --version
conda 23.5.0
PS C:\Users\Julián\Documents\proyectos\conda> conda info --env
# conda environments:
#
                         C:\Users\Julián\Documents\proyectos\conda\entorno
base                     C:\Users\Julián\miniconda3
entorni                  C:\Users\Julián\miniconda3\envs\entorni
name                     C:\Users\Julián\miniconda3\envs\name
poi                      C:\Users\Julián\miniconda3\envs\poi
tori                     C:\Users\Julián\miniconda3\envs\tori

PS C:\Users\Julián\Documents\proyectos\conda> conda activate tori
PS C:\Users\Julián\Documents\proyectos\conda> conda deactivate
PS C:\Users\Julián\Documents\proyectos\conda>
```

If i do the same in a powershell without vs code giveme this:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.

To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - cmd.exe
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

I try with conda init powershell command but the error persist.

How can i resolve this?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: `conda init powershell` modifies PowerShell's `$PROFILE` file. If you're using the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) for Visual Studio Code, make sure that profile loading isn't disabled (search for `powershell profile` in the settings).

Comment: I don't use powershell extension in vs code. But i download that and verify this setting. The error persist.

Comment: This command `conda run` will meet your needs without running `conda active`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this command `conda run` will meet your needs without running `conda active`.

Vscode will automatically activate the conda environment.

Comment: Yes, i can run the code supusedly in the conda enviroment because i tried `conda info --envs`  command to watch the current enviroment but not works (in powershell and bash)